# Rails assets path incorrect in a scoped production application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I've got an app that I'm trying to deploy to a subdirectory in production. Therefore, I have added a `scope` block that reads:

```
scope "/sapa" do
```

This works fine for the main code, but for some reason all assets (as rendered by the assets pipeline) begin with `/assets` instead of `/sapa/assets` (i.e. `

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset pipeline doesn't care about the routes. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-_assets_-path)'s how to change the assets path:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have resolved the path issue. Now I just have to figure out why my .js shows up properly while my .css does not…